# apt-get upgrade failing due to dependency issue

Tags: upgrade, apt

I am running 12.04 LTS on a ASUS custom build server.   I apologize in advance as my skills are a bit rusty in linux as I spend more time working with networking gear these days.

I am running `sudo apt-get upgrade` after I ran `sudo apt-get update` and I get the follwoing:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic but it is not installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.39.47) but 3.2.0.40.48 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So when I run `sudo apt-get -f install` I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic linux-image-server linux-server
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.2.0 linux-source-3.2.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-server linux-server
2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 124 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 150 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 373700 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic_3.2.0-40.64_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic_3.2.0-40.64_amd64.deb (--unpack):
failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during ./boot/abi-3.2.0-40-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-40-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-40-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-40-generic_3.2.0-40.64_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

As you can see there is a disk full error message so I tried to purge some of the unused kernels following a process posted on another question I found.

I ran `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic` where x.x.x.x is a kernal version I was not using but I get the same error of suggesting to run `apt-get -f install` I got when I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Is there something I am just not remembering to help me clear space up here or another way to purge unneeded kernel images?

An attempt to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` results:

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.99ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
 linux-image-server depends on linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.39.47); however:
  Package linux-image-server is not configured yet.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.39.47); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.40.48.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-server
 linux-server
 initramfs-tools
```

Results of `df -h`.  Couldn't remember that command for the life of me to see the space.  Get a good laugh at the boot size especially since it is on that 500GB drive with not much being used there.   I can't steal from /dev/sdb1 as that is isolated physical drive for share space among all users and can be taken out and moved to any system easily should the need arise.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/NAS-root  455G   11G  421G   3% /
udev                  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 791M  768K  790M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1             1.8T  929G  813G  54% /media/windows
/dev/sda1             228M  228M     0 100% /boot
```

Can't remember when I built this server but it will be the last time I let it select sizes for partitions automatically.   I am guessing my best bet is to follow these instructions for increasing partition size?  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1219270

Any worries with data corruption by stealing from /dev/mapper/NAS-root?

Well I finally cleared space up correctly but I am still getting a dependency issue when trying to run `sudo apt-get -f install`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
 linux-image-server linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
 linux-image-server linux-server
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 124 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,320 B of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
 linux-image-server depends on linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.39.47); however:
  Package linux-image-server is not configured yet.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.39.47); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.40.48.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-server
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not sure how to even begin to fix this issue since there is a newer version of the kernal file there but it is looking for an older version.

Comment: Please post the output of df -h command.

Comment: You can manually clear some space. Try deleting temp and cache files.

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo apt-get -f install` did not work, then try this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

or,

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

For `sudo apt-get -f install`, try running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I ran `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`  The clean executes successfully but autoremove produces the same error as the upgrade.

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` results in an error as well stating no space left on device.   See output above.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Sorry!